# IText : Add an image on a header with an absolute position

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

I want to place a header on each page of my PDF.
The text part of the header is done but I can't find a way to place an image.

```
public static class Header extends PdfPageEventHelper {             
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        try{
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();      

            /*
              Some code to place my text in the header
            */

            Image imgSoc = Image.getInstance("C:\\...\\Logo.jpg");
            imgSoc.scaleToFit(110,110);
            imgSoc.setAbsolutePosition(390, 720);

            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            ct.addText(new Chunk(imgSoc,0,0));
            ct.go();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure I'm doing this the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already are two answers using tables.

Tables can be very helpful to create a dynamic layout of different header parts (document title, document version, page number, logo, ...).

But if you don't need that, already have everything in place like the OP has, you can simply add the image at a fixed position with a fixed size:

```
public static class Header extends PdfPageEventHelper {             
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        try
        {
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();      

            /*
              Some code to place some text in the header
            */

            Image imgSoc = Image.getInstance("C:\\...\\Logo.jpg");
            imgSoc.scaleToFit(110,110);
            imgSoc.setAbsolutePosition(390, 720);

            cb.addImage(imgSoc);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**PS**: If you really use the same logo on all pages, you had better read the image file into an `Image` instance only once (e.g. in the constructor or `onOpenDocument`), hold that instance in a variable and re-use it again and again. This way you include the image data only once in the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

A way to achieve this is to create the header as a table:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
Image imgSoc = Image.getInstance("C:\\...\\Logo.jpg");
imgSoc.scaleToFit(110,110);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(imgSoc , true);
cell.setBorder(0);
table.addCell(cell);
float[] columnWidths = new float[] { 100};
table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
table.setWidths(columnWidths);
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.addElement(table);
ct.setSimpleColumn(36, 0, 559, 806); //Position goes here
ct.go();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use iText Table in such a way that , you can show your logo either left or right depending upon the user choice.

```
            Chunk header = new Chunk("your header text", headerFont);
            Image logo = Image.getInstance("../../..");
            // your image path
            logo.scaleAbsolute(80f, 80f);
            logo.scalePercent(100);
            table = new PdfPTable(3);
            table.setWidthPercentage(100);

            PdfPCell detailCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(header));
            detailCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            detailCell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
            detailCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);

            PdfPCell logoRightCell = new PdfPCell();
            logoRightCell.setFixedHeight(80);
            logoRightCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            logoRightCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

            PdfPCell logoLeftCell = new PdfPCell();
            logoLeftCell.setFixedHeight(80);
            logoLeftCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            logoLeftCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

            if (true) {
                String logoAlign = "left";
                if (logoAlign.compareTo("Left") == 0) {
                    logo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    logoLeftCell.addElement(logo);
                } else {
                    logo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                    logoRightCell.addElement(logo);
                }
            }
            String headerAlign = "Center";
            if (headerAlign.compareTo("Center") == 0) {
                table.setWidths(new int[] { 2, 7, 2 });
                table.addCell(logoLeftCell);
                table.addCell(detailCell);
                table.addCell(logoRightCell);
            } else if (headerAlign.compareTo("Left") == 0) {
                table.setWidths(new int[] { 7, 2, 2 });
                table.addCell(detailCell);
                table.addCell(logoLeftCell);
                table.addCell(logoRightCell);
            } else {
                table.setWidths(new int[] { 2, 2, 7 });
                table.addCell(logoLeftCell);
                table.addCell(logoRightCell);
                table.addCell(detailCell);
            }

            //
            table.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getWidth()
                    - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin());
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(), document
                    .getPageSize().getHeight() - document.topMargin() + 20,
                    writer.getDirectContent());
        }
 document.add(table);
```